# Apache why is KeepAlive off by default (in this era of HTTP/1.1)

Tags: apache, http, keep-alive

For what reason would Apache choose to have KeepAlive disabled by default?  It seems there is more to be gained from leaving it on as it saves the system from a lot of unnecessary TCP open/connect calls for a single connection.  What are the downsides and are they prevalent enough to warrant disabling by default?

Answer (score 0):

[It doesn't](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#keepalive):

> Default:  KeepAlive On

If you want to know why one would want to deactivate KeepAlive, I guess to safe server resources (memory).